# AAD Authentication with JSON WebAPI consumed by Power BI

Tags: json, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, powerbi

I've written my own web service in ASP.NET Core 2 that authenticates against AzureAD and provides a JSON endpoint which I'm trying to consume in Power BI. When I set authentication to Organizational Account and click sign in, I get the following error:

> We were unable to connect because this credential type isn’t supported
>   for this resource. Please choose another credential type.

Is there something I need to change in my service so that it will work correctly with Power BI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Json-AAD-unable-to-connect-because-this-credential-type-isn-t/m-p/332261), AAD auth is not supported:

> I am afraid that the AAD authentication type is not supported in Power BI Desktop, please vote up the following ideas.
>
> https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31405525-support-azure-active-dir...
>
> https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15039609-active-directory-authent...
>
> Regards,
>   Lydia

I ended up using auth tokens to get around this unfortunate limitation.